# Is there a penalty for kicking a PAT from the 2 yard line in the NFL?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl

This year the NFL changed the way extra points work so that 2-point-conversion attempts are snapped from the 2 yard line as they always were, but extra points are now snapped from the 15. If a team lined up from the 2 yard line (maybe the told the officials they would be going for 2) and kicked an extra point, is there a penalty? What if they attempt a drop-kick after snapping the ball from the 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have happened during a [preseason](https://www.espn.com/nfl/game/_/gameId/401326351) game between the Buccaneers and the Bengals in 2021.

In that instance (after a period of confusion) although the kick succeeded, no points were awarded and the try was not reattempted.  Technically, there was no penalty.

A discussion of the play is on [footballzebras.com](https://www.footballzebras.com/2021/08/faked-extra-point-is-good-but-its-worth-0-points/)

Answer (score 4):

There is no explicit penalty or foul in the books for this; that would be listed in Rule 9, section 1, in the [2015 Rulebook](http://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2015-nfl-rulebook/#rule-9.-scrimmage-kick).

Rule 11, section 3, states simply that:

> The Try begins when the Referee sounds the whistle for play to start. The team that scored the touchdown shall put the ball in play:
>
> > anywhere on or between the inbound lines
> >
> > 15 yards from the defensive team's goal line for a Try-kick
> >
> > two yards from the defensive team’s goal line for a Try by pass or run
>
> Note 1: A team's choice is not final and is subject to change following a team timeout or accepted penalty
>
> ...
>
> Note 4: If the ball has been declared ready for play by the Referee, and the offensive team wants to change the location of the ball, they can do so by calling a timeout.

If it were to happen (that a team lined up on the 2 and then kicked the try), I assume the referees would simply prevent them from lining up to kick the ball.  If a drop-kick occurred, it would possibly count as a personal foul - unsportsmanlike conduct (Rule 12):

> SECTION 3 - UNSPORTSMANLIKE CONDUCT
>
> > ARTICLE 1. PROHIBITED ACTS
> >
> > > There shall be no unsportsmanlike conduct. This applies to any act which is contrary to the generally understood principles of sportsmanship.

It is not specifically enumerated in the list of unsportsmanlike actions, although the list is not intended to be exhaustive.  I would surmise if this actually were to occur, it might be added to the list the next year.

Alternately, it's possible it would simply not count and they would lose the opportunity to re-try.  Personally, that feels like the better option: the rules don't allow for a kick from the 2, so if you want to kick from the two, feel free, you just give up your point.

Comment: I know this would never happen in a real game, but during normal play there is always the theoretical possibility that if a runner is advancing the ball and realizes that he will not score or pick up a first-down or whatever he can decide to drop-kick the ball. Is that possibility taken away on a two-point conversion?

Comment: I certainly think the rules intend for that not to be permitted.  I'm not sure the rules are written in such a way as to clarify what _would_ happen in that case.  And, in a league with Bill Belichick, who knows what might occur in a real game...

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time Belicheck [called for a drop-kick PAT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3EaLfpZjaw)

Comment: That aside, I can't imagine it being a high percentage play; drop kicks aren't used for a reason (you do give up a blocker after all!).  But whether a QB who recognized an impossible coverage situation at the snap (and who was already in shotgun) could step back a few steps and drop kick legally - I don't know, though I think it should be illegal.

Answer (score -2):

If a team attempted anything except a run or pass from the 2 yard after a successful touchdown during regulation, such as a placekick, dropkick or punt, then that 2 point conversion attempt would be deemed to have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Are you able to add references to support this assertion?

Comment: This seems like a valid interpretation, since the rules state "...shall put the ball in play: 15 yards from the defensive team's goal line for a Try-kick [or] two yards from the defensive team’s goal line for a Try by pass or run."  Since the offense puts the ball in play from the 2, they must be in the try by pass or run. When the ball is snapped, they are committed to that. Since they did not pass or run into the end zone, they were not successful, as the location they snapped from dictates their viable means of scoring according to that rule.